# Ни он ни она не хотели уходить первым?

Tags: род, множественное-число, согласование

Подскажите, пожалуйста, насколько правильно это предложение. 
Тут и он, и она, и множественное число и в конце ещё надо поставить прилагательное в каком-то роде.
Может быть, у вас есть идеи, как это можно перефразировать?

Comment: Может «Никто из них [двоих] не хотел уходить первым»?

Comment: Во-первых, по мне тут не хватает запятой: «ни он, ни она». Потом, если «не хотели», то «первыми». В остальном же не вижу никаких проблем. Но это предложение может означать только, что они должны были уходить вместе, вдвоем; если же по отдельности, то см. комментарий Yellow Sky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*«Ни он, ни она»* обычно согласуется с множественным числом, поэтому сочетание с *«уходить первым»* звучит неправильно.

Если имеется ввиду, что ни один не хотел уходить раньше другого, то стоит перестроить фразу.
Например, *«Ни он  не хотел уходить первым, ни она.»*

Comment: Видимо, придётся смириться с тем, что надо перефразировать. Почему мне не очень подходит вариант: "Никто из них [двоих] не хотел уходить первым". Потому что тут больше ощущается повествование от третьего лица. А если у меня фокус исходит от героини и постоянно вставляются её мысли, то использовать "их", это уже уход в сторону автора. Ваш вариант мне больше подходит. Но такой вынос "ни она" далеко назад... Мне это ещё надо переварить. Спасибо. Я приму ваш ответ, как правильный.

Answer (score 1):

Предложение выглядит как результат пропуска местоимения, когда в оригинале оно звучало как "Никто - ни он, ни она - не хотел уходить первым", при этом сказуемое ошибочно употреблено во множественном числе. Может быть верно как в вышеуказанном мной варианте, так и в виде "Ни он, ни она не хотели уходить первыми", но не в вашей, Виталий, версии (если не вспоминать ещё и о пунктуации)